# Rotate from 0<=X<infinity

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, rotation

Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region below the graph of 
y = e^(−x) about the x-axis for 0 ≤ x < ∞

With that given expression I tried to do it by doing the following code:
RevolutionPlot3D[{y = e^(-x)}, {0}, {x, 0, infinity}]
Which I believe is the correct translation of the given expression, however I'm getting an error from it.
Could someone help me with where I'm going wrong with the rotation? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check documentation before posting... try this `RevolutionPlot3D[{x, Exp[-x]}, {x, 0, 9}, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1/2]` Its is not possible to plot anything up to `Infinity` given your screen being probably finite :) But the volume you can compute by simple integration.

Comment: Have you tried writing down any formulae for volume? Start with cylinder of height `dx` and radius `Exp[-x]`

Comment: @PlatoManiac I think the plot should actually be of `{Exp[-x],x]}`. Note the question asks for revolution about the `x` axis and `RevolutionPlot` rotates about `z` so you need to swap `x->z` and `y->x` as you read the docs.

Comment: @george2079 Ya missed that :(  thx for correcting.

Answer (score 2):

Let's approximate our body with a set of cylinders with height `dx`

```
dx = 0.1;
Graphics3D[(Cylinder[{{#, 0, 0}, {# + dx, 0, 0}}, Exp[-#]] & /@ 
   Range[0, 3, dx]), Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"}]
```

[image]

To calculate volume itself we need to sum all cylinders, cylinder's volume is $\pi r^2 dx = \pi \exp(-x)^2 dx$

with $dx$ -> $0$ we will get integral:

```
Integrate[Pi (Exp[-x])^2, {x, 0, Infinity}]
(* Pi/2 *)
```

If you really want to use `RevolutionPlot3D` for visualizing, you can of course follow the comments and keep in mind @george2079 correction

```
RevolutionPlot3D[{Exp[-x], x}, {x, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Mesh -> None, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the clarity, I was struggling to get through the API and your explanation was very clear. Thank you for the strong visuals and good description of how to proceed with it.